# working with sitemap path in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

can i know how to work with sitemap path in asp.net is possible examle please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ASP.NET Site Maps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy2ykkab.aspx)

> The simplest way to create a site map
>   is to create an XML file named
>   Web.sitemap that organizes the pages
>   in the site hierarchically. This site
>   map is automatically picked up by the
>   default site-map provider for ASP.NET.

Comment: Thank you i got it Mr. Shoban